# Knockout async observable patterns turns into an infinity loop

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view like this:

```
<xsl:comment>ko with: resolve(1)</xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment>ko template: { name: typeName }</xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment>/ko</xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment>/ko</xsl:comment>
```

and a viewmodel (the view's datacontext) with a method like this:

```
self.resolve = function (id) {
    var obs = ko.observable(null);
    self.getItemByIdAsync(id).done(obs);
    return obs;
};
```

For some reason this turns into an infinity loop. My guess is that the with-binding thinks that it depends on the value of the observable `obs` and when it is updated the with-binding tries to run resolve again, and again and again...

How can I modify this code so that resolve is run once only?

---

What I'm trying to do is to have a dynamic viewmodel that adapts to what the view wants to present. If the view tries to resolve an item within a certain viewmodel-context, it should load this item async, create a new viewmodel for it and add it as a child-viewmodel to the datacontext-vm.

I have seen this async observable pattern when elsewhere but I seem to be using it wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct, `self.resolve` is called whenever you're trying to set `obs`, the following is from [knockout doc](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html):

> If the expression you supply involves any observable values, the expression will be re-evaluated whenever any of those observables change.

I don't know the reason why you use `self.resolve` function with `with`, my approach to this problem would probably look like:

```
function ViewMode() {
    ...
    self.obs = ko.observable(null);

    self.resolve = function (id) {
        self.getItemByIdAsync(id).done(self.obs);
    };

    self.resolve(1); // kick start the UI with id = 1
}
```

Then in the view, simply use `data-bind="with: obs"`.

Comment: I was trying to, dynamically from the view, get any item async by id without having to have observable-declarations for each item. But maybee (probably) I should rethink my design a bit.